# Testing Traversing Class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, azure-table-storage

I have 2 classes: `ATableEntity` and `ATableEntityRepository`.

`ATableEntity` implements [ITableEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity_members.aspx). I want to test `ATableEntity`'s write and read method. The problem is that this class does not know anything about CloudTable or StorageAccount, which I think is correct and intend to maintain. `ATableEntityRepository` on the other hand does know everthing about the underling infra...

My question is: What should my tests look-like?

Answer (score 0):

As per the description, `ATableEntity` implements `ITableEntity` which means, `ReadEntity` and `WriteEntity` are overridden. The class `ATableEntity`doesn't need to know anything about `CloudTable`. All you have to do in your test method is call the mock implementation of `ATableEntityRepository` to read and write the entities.